# Flutter - Always execute a function when the page appears

Tags: dart, flutter

How could I make the `name()` function run whenever the `Page1` page appeared?

In the code below before going to `Page2` I execute the `dispose()`
Already inside `Page2` if I click the back button or the physical button of Android the function `name()` is not executed, but if I click the `'go to Page1'` button the function `name()` is executed.

Could you help me to always execute the `name()` function when `Page1` appears?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/page2': (BuildContext context) => new Page2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String nameScreen;

  String name() {
    return 'foo1';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.nameScreen = name();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    this.nameScreen = '';
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Page 1'),
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('go to Page2'),
              onPressed: () async {
                dispose();
                bool isLoggedIn = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2');
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                  setState((){
                    this.nameScreen = name();
                  });
                }
              },
            ),            
            new Text(
              '$nameScreen',              
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold( 
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Page 2'),
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373)
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('go back to Page1'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to call `dispose` at all when you are willing to `pop` and change `State` later, since `dispose` will remove the current object from the tree, which does not translate to the logic you are trying to develop.

You can indeed override the `BackButton` and pass the same call of `Navigator.pop(context, result)` to it. Check the following example I have tweaked your code a little bit to show you the difference between each `State` of your `nameScreen` field. I hope this helps you.

[image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String nameScreen = "";

  String name() {
    return 'foo1';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.nameScreen = "From initState";

  }

@override
void dipose(){
    super.dispose();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page 1'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF26C6DA),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('go to Page2'),
              onPressed: () async {
                //dispose(); ///No need for dispose
                String result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2');

                  setState((){
                    this.nameScreen = result;
                  });

              },
            ),
            Text(
              '$nameScreen',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: ()async{
            Navigator.pop(context,"From BackButton");
          }),
          title: const Text('Page 2'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE57373)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                child: const Text('go back to Page1'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, "From RaisedButton");
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: @azira Thanks for your help, just not working if the user comes back by the physical button of Android. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: One way to solve the problem was I just added `if(result == null) {result = "Android back button";}` on top of `setState` in case the user uses the physical Android button

Comment: I definitely think this a a major piece of missing functionality in the flutter framework. Detecting when a widget comes back into focus is such an obvious use case (refreshing data from some remote source for instance). Something akin to the onResume callback of native Android.

Comment: Just for the specific use case you mentioned. You can use a StreamBuilder which will listen to the changes on the source and awlays rebuild your widget according to the changes

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this is to use the `.whenComplete()` method on the Navigator widget.

Suppose you are going to the second page from the first page. Here you have to pass the `functionThatSetsTheState` as a pointer to the navigation part of your code.

The function looks like this and should be in a Stateful Widget.

```
void functionThatSetsTheState(){
    setState(() {});
}
```

Your navigation code for `OnPressed`, `OnTap`, `OnLongPress`, etc.

```dart
Navigator.of(context)
    .push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondPage()))
    .whenComplete(() => {functionThatSetsTheState()});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the back button on the second screen. And instead of system closing, do

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () {
       print('back pressed');
       Navigator.pop(context, "From BackButton");
       return true;
      },
    child: Scaffold(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use RouteObserves if you want to execute some function whenever your page appears, you will have to implement RouteAware on the page where you want to run execute the function whenever the screens appears, you're gonna have to do something like this on ur Page1

```
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>(); // add this on your main class
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(),
    navigatorObservers: [routeObserver], // add observer here;
  ));
} 





// your page where func should run whenever this page appears
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget with RouteAware {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String nameScreen = "";

  String name() {
    return 'foo1';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.nameScreen = "From initState";

  }

 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

// implementing RouteAware method
void didPush() {
// Route was pushed onto navigator and is now topmost route.
    name(); // your func goes here
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page 1'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF26C6DA),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('go to Page2'),
              onPressed: () async {
                //dispose(); ///No need for dispose
                String result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2');

                  setState((){
                    this.nameScreen = result;
                  });

              },
            ),
            Text(
              '$nameScreen',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can head over to this link for more explanation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

Comment: Overriding didPopNext allows you to do something when the next page on the stack pops and the implementer is visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to navigate from page 1 to page 2 and immediately after page 2 loads execute a function in page 2 (useful for showing a dialog immediately when page 2 loads) :

You can do this by adding in **initState** or **didChangeDependencies** of page 2 :

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    // Function to execute
  });
```

If you want to add some logic to put a condition before executing the function, simply push an argument in your page 1 :

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page-2", arguments : true)
```

Finnaly the code in page 2 becomes:

```
 _functionToExecute(){
  print("done");
  }
 @override
 void didChangeDependencies() {
 
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    if(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments)
    _functionToExecute()
  });
 }
```