# Initialize StateFulWidget every time page loads

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a basic Mobile page in flutter that gets some data from a backend service.

I have a StateFulWidget, very similar to example mentioned here

https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-show-progress-indicator-in-flutter-when-there-is-a-task-that-is

Is there a way to initialize the StateFulWidget (i.e. loadData() every time the page is loaded. Example user navigates to a different page, and navigates back to home page, can the loadData() be called again)

Comment: I think this is the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027124/flutter-always-execute-a-function-when-the-page-appears/47028152#47028152