# How to refresh the main page after opening a page from an android drawer menu with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a problem, I have a main activity where I have loaded several widget classes so far so good.
now what I want to do is refresh the main page after closing a page that has been triggered in a Drawer menu.

It works if the button is directly on the main page, but if the action is triggered from the Drawer menu it does not work.

Example of screen or it works very well
[image]

Option 2
It should look like this. but it doesn't work when I call the page from the Drawer menu
[image]

reference link:
[How to go back and refresh the previous page in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830553/how-to-go-back-and-refresh-the-previous-page-in-flutter)
[How to refresh a page after back button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933272/how-to-refresh-a-page-after-back-button-pressed?rq=1)

Would anyone have an idea.
Here is the code to use for option 1 with the button on the main page:

```
new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: ()=>
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>new PageHomeContent()),)
                  .then((val)=>{getRefreshRequests()}),
          child: Text('Refresh', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), ), color: Colors.purple,
          elevation: 2.0,
        ),
```

[image]

It is important to know that I have created a class for the Drawer menu here. it is a little long but I you essential

```
final Color primaryColor = Colors.white;
final Color activeColor = Colors.grey.shade800;
final Color dividerColor = Colors.grey.shade600;

class BuildDrawer extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _BuildDrawer createState() => _BuildDrawer();
}

class _BuildDrawer extends State<BuildDrawer> {
  //region [ ATTRIUTS ]
  final String image = 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/3463865?s=460&u=c0fab43e4b105e9745dc3b5cf61e21e79c5406c2&v=4';

  List<dynamic> menuGroupList = [];
  Future<List<dynamic>> _futureMenuGroupList;
  bool _infiniteStop;

  //MenuItemGroupModel menuItemGroup = new MenuItemGroupModel();
  List<dynamic> menuItemList = [];
  Future<List<dynamic>> _futureMenuItemList;
  //Future<MenuItemGroupModel> _futureMenuItemGroup;
  bool _infiniteItemStop;

  //endregion

  @override
  void initState() {
    _futureMenuGroupList = fetchMenuWPList();
    _infiniteStop = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: OvalRightBorderClipper(),
      child: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 40),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: primaryColor,
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45)]),
          width: 300,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        //Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageHomeContent(),),);
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>new PageHomeContent()),)
                            .then((val)=>{ new MainPage() });
                      },
                      child:
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.format_list_bulleted,
                                  color: activeColor,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Text("Home Content",  ),
                                Spacer(),
                              ]
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: dividerColor,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
//end Class

//region [ MENU ITEM PAGE ]

//endregion
```

Main Page Class [ `MainPage` ]

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //MainPage({Key key, this.title}): super(key: key);
  //final String title;

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<WPMainPage> {

  //region [ ATTRIBUTS ]
  List<dynamic> featuredArticles = [];
  List<dynamic> latestArticles = [];
  List<dynamic> pageList = [];
  List<dynamic> menuGroupList = [];
  List<dynamic> categoryHomeList = [];

  Future<List<dynamic>> _futurePageList;
  Future<List<dynamic>> _futureFeaturedArticles;
  Future<List<dynamic>> _futureLastestArticles;
  Widget widgetCategoryBuilder=new Container();

  final _categoryRepository = CategoryRepository();

  ScrollController _controller;
  int page = 1;
  bool _showLoadingPage = true;
  bool _showLoadingCategoryHome = true;
  bool _infiniteStop;
  double heightNoInternet = 280.0;

  // Firebase Cloud Messeging setup
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  //endregion

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureFeaturedArticles = fetchFeaturedArticles(1);
    _futureLastestArticles = fetchLatestArticles(1);
    _futurePageList = fetchPageList();
    getCategoriesOnLocal();

    _controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0, keepScrollOffset: true);
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);

    _infiniteStop = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(Constant.APP_NAME_LONG),
          actions: getActionAppBarButton(context: context),
        ),
        drawer: BuildDrawer(),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
                children:
                getWidgetList()
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }


  getRefreshRequests() async {
    getCategoriesOnLocal();
    //Tools.mySnackBar(context, ' m s g TEST 1 ');
  }

  getWidgetList() {
    List<Widget> itemList = new List<Widget>();

    itemList.add(
        new Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: ()=>
                  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>new PageHomeContent()),)
                      .then((val)=>{ getRefreshRequests() }),
              child: Text('Refresh', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), ), color: Colors.purple,
              elevation: 2.0,
            ),

          ],
        )

    );

    itemList.add(
        getPagebuilderList(isShowTitle: false)
    );

    itemList.add(
        featuredPostBuildSlider(_futureFeaturedArticles)
    );

    /*itemList.add(
      featuredPost(_futureFeaturedArticles),
    );*/
    itemList.add(
        widgetCategoryBuilder
    );


    itemList.add(
        latestPosts(_futureLastestArticles)
    );

    return itemList;
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    var isEnd = _controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange;
    if (isEnd) {
      setState(() {
        page += 1;
        _futureLastestArticles = fetchLatestArticles(page);
      });
    }
  }

  //region [ ALL POST | RECENTS POST ]
  //endregion

  //region [ POST FEATURED | Swiper ]
  //endregion

  //region [ PAGES ]
  //endregion

  //region [ CATEGORIES LOCAL --> ON LIGNE ]
  void getCategoriesOnLocal() async {
    try {
      await _categoryRepository.getCategories().then((itemList) {
        if (itemList != null) {
          setState(() {
            categoryHomeList = itemList;
          });
          getCategoryBuilder();
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      Tools.println("Error: getCategoriesOnLocal: $e");
    }
  }
  getCategoryBuilder() {
    List<Widget> itemWidgetList=[];
    if(  _showLoadingCategoryHome) {
      if (categoryHomeList.length > 0) {
        for (Category category in categoryHomeList) {
          if (category.count > 0) {
            itemWidgetList.add(
                getItemArticle(category: category)
            );
          }
        }
        widgetCategoryBuilder=  Column( children: itemWidgetList );
      } else {
        widgetCategoryBuilder=  Container();
      }
    } else {
      widgetCategoryBuilder= Container();
    }
    setState(() {
      widgetCategoryBuilder = widgetCategoryBuilder;
    });
    return widgetCategoryBuilder;
  }
  Widget getItemArticle({Category category}) {
    return
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('${category.name}',
                  style: homeTitleTextStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
                Spacer(),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CategoryArticles(category.id, category.name),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child:  Text('See More',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
                ),

              ],),
          ),
          new CategoryHomeBuilder( categorieId: category.id),
        ],
      );
  }
//endregion

}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for a better response.

I replaced the `BuildDrawer` class with a `getBuildDrawer()` method in the main class.

And it works very well but I would have preferred to put it in a separate class, so that I can use it in another page ...

```
getBuildDrawer() {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: OvalRightBorderClipper(),
      child: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 40),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: primaryColor,
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45)]),
          width: 300,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>new PageHomeContent()),)
          .then((val)=>{ getRefreshRequests() });
                      },
                      child:
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.format_list_bulleted,
                                  color: activeColor,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Text("Home Content",  ),
                                Spacer(),
                              ]
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: dividerColor,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I just want to say I'm in the exact situation.  I am about to just turn my drawer into a method in the same class - but there has to be a better way?  Did you ever find one out?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to refresh the page just putting setState(getRefreshRequests()) when you return from navigator, that's because the page don't know that you put a new widget on screen